# Что может возвращать конструктор класса, кроме объекта этого класса?

Tags: ruby

Имеем описание класса:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
  end
end
```

IDE RubyMine предлагает описать метод `initialize`.
Описание является комментарий к методу, по котором потом можно построить документацию `Yard` или `RDoc`.
IDE добавляет такой `# @return [Object]` шаблон для описания.

Что, кроме самого объекта класса может возвращать конструктор класса?

Answer (score 4):

Не имеет значения, что возвращать. Значение буде проигнорировано. И `initialize` не является конструктором как таковым. Метод `new` вызывает `initialize`, но возвращенное значение просто выбрасывает.